# Finding the length of a finite cover of a set of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $A$ be the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $\{I_n\}$ be a finite collection of open intervals covering A. Show that $\sum l(I_n) \geq 1$

I'm not really sure what the question is getting at. I feel like it has to do something with the density of the rationals in Q making it impossible for the $I_n$s to be disjoint, but I don't know how to get there

Comment: Be careful. The intervals could actually be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: $(-1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\cup (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 2)$ is an open cover of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ that does not cover $[0,1]$. And when the cover is by finitely many open intervals, this is really the only exception (and proving this gets you well on your way to proving the desired result).

Comment: Why $1\over{\sqrt2}$ and not some other rational